# JPA Criteria API count number of entities for specific day/month/year

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, criteria-api

I have the following query which I would like to convert to Criteria API. I'm having a few difficulties since I'm very new. The SQL statement is the following:

```
SELECT
  dayofweek(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.startTime / 1000)) as d,
  count(*)
FROM persons p
GROUP BY dayofweek(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.startTime / 1000))  
having d  = 1
```

startTime is a long(milliseconds) representation of Date.
Additionally when performing the Query I will be asking for the day/month etc with their numeric values. So for monday let's say the day parameter would be '1'

How can I form this Query with Criteria API?

Right now I have the following:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<Person> root = cq.from(Person.class);

    cq.select(cb.count(root));
    Expression<Integer> expStartTime = root.get("startTime");
    Expression<Integer> expConvertedTime =  cb.function("day", Integer.class,
            expStartTime);

    cq.groupBy(root.get("startTime"));

    cq.having(cb.equal(expConvertedTime, 1));
```

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to form the criteria query. How can I use the Criteria API to do the dayOfWeek function and compare it to the given date parameter. I give some initial code I have done till now